# Open Bitlocker USB stick on OS X

Tags: macos, windows, encryption

I have a USB stick encrypted by Windows 7 built-in tool (bitlocker). I would like to open it on my OS X El Capitan.

When I open it, all I get is a file "BitLockerToGo.exe" and another "Read Me.url"

I found some pieces here and there but no full procedure for mac.

Comment: How about http://www.m3datarecovery.com/mac-bitlocker/open-bitlocker-encrypted-usb-drive-mac-osx.html ?

Comment: @Marthijn "M3 bitlocker" is worth mentionning: The licensing model discouraged me from using it but reader is free to chose.

Answer (score 10):

Actually I asked after some success because I thought it would benefit everyone ;-)

Here is the complete process. Some links are missing because I don't have enough reputation to embed them all. Sorry about that.

High-level, we "just" need dislocker.

But to install it, there are some **dependencies** to resolve... we need:

1. "Fuse for OS X"

   - Simply download the .img on their site, open and run the .pkg installer
2. Xcode command-line developers tools

   - I'm not sure what's the generic answer.
   - Open a terminal, and type

     ```
     xcode-select --install
     ```

     - If you get an error "-bash: xcode-select: command not found", you need to install Xcode from the App store, then start again this command.
     - If an alert windows popup asking if you want to install, click on "install" button.
     - If it prints error "xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, [...]", you're all set.
3. "Homebrew"

   - Following instruction on their website, type following in terminal:

     ```
     /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
     ```
   - If you get an error about Xcode tools not being installed whereas you did install it, then change the path to Xcode:

     ```
     sudo xcode-select -switch /
     ```
4. and obviously [dislocker](https://github.com/Aorimn/dislocker) !

   - Download ZIP (available in green button "Clone or Download" on the right)
   - Extract ZIP content
   - Open terminal and change directory to the dislocker-master directory
   - Compile and install dislocker:

     ```
     brew install src/dislocker.rb
     ```

     - If you get an error about Xcode tools not being installed whereas you did install it, then change the path like this:

       ```
       sudo xcode-select -switch /
       ```

---

Don't be desperate, it's now **time to mount the USB stick** !

But it's not gonna be trivial...

1. Identify the device of the USB stick, using Disk Utility:

   - Open Disk Utility and select the USB stick drive. Somewhere you should get something like "disk3s1". Replace this example with your actual value in following lines.
   - Keep Disk Utility open, it will be used in next steps
2. Eject the USB drive for example from Disk Utility (Unmount button)
3. Create a directory for the decrypted file

   ```
   sudo mkdir /tmp/mydrive
   ```

   Warning: this directory will have strange characteristics: it appears with "ls" but not with "ls -l" and not in the Finder wherever it is, moreover the content can't be listed, and trying to delete it often fails with strange error messages. That's why I put it in /tmp which is cleaned at every reboot.
4. Decrypt the USB stick with dislocker. If disk is "disk3s1" and the password is "MyPassword", the command will look like:

   ```
   sudo dislocker-file -V /dev/disk3s1 -v -uMyPassword -r -- /tmp/mydrive
   ```
5. Add the disk image to Disk Utility and mount it

   ```
   sudo hdiutil attach -imagekey diskimage-class=CRawDiskImage /tmp/mydrive/dislocker-file
   ```

   Note: Don't try to list "/tmp/mydrive/dislocker-file" by yourself. Just assume it is there and write the path as is.

Hourray !!!, the new drive is there !

---

Because really nothing is easy, **to clean-up** you need to do the following:

1. Unmount the drive

   - For example from your friend Disk Utility, select its icon and click on "Unmount" button
2. Get rid of the image

   - From "Disk Utility", select the greyed drive, and from the menu "File" select "Eject".
3. Detach the fuse volume

   ```
   sudo  hdiutil detach /tmp/mydrive/
   ```

Only now the directory /tmp/mydrive is a plain directory that can be deleted...

---

As you noticed the process is definitely complex and finally I just get a read-only drive.
I'm interested by any better answer.

Comment: `brew install src/dislocker.rb` failed on the `make` step.  Oddly, manually running `cmake`, `make`, and `make install` succeeded and installed it into the Cellar.

Comment: Jonatan$ sudo dislocker -V /dev/disk2s1 --user-password xxx -- ~/Decrypted-disk

Enter the user password: 

fuse: invalid argument `/Users/Jonatan/Decrypted-disk' 

what can be the error? I have tried with both an existing directory and a non-existing directory...

Answer (score 9):

I'd like to share my experience on High Sierra, as it seems to be even simpler.

## Installation

### [Homebrew](https://brew.sh)

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

### [Fuse for macOS](https://osxfuse.github.io)

```
brew cask install osxfuse
```

#### Notes

- To install and/or use osxfuse you may need to enable their kernel extension in `System Preferences → Security & Privacy → General`
- Make sure to reboot before proceeding further (as osxfuse advises to do so).

### [dislocker](https://github.com/Aorimn/dislocker)

```
brew install dislocker
```

## Operation

### Mount

```
# to unlock the dislocker image
sudo dislocker -v -V /dev/disk3s1 -r -uPASSWORD ~/mydrive

# to mount the unlocked image
sudo hdiutil attach /tmp/mydrive/dislocker-file -imagekey diskimage-class=CRawDiskImage -mountpoint /Volumes/mydrive
```

### Unmount

```
# unmount the unlocked image
sudo hdiutil detach /Volumes/mydrive

# release the unlocked bitlocker
sudo hdiutil detach /tmp/mydrive
```

### Script

I've also created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/dumbledore/2c9f2a6410763c3f96516945b65bc5bb) to ease the mount/unmount procedure:

```
# mount, will be available at /Volumes/bitlocker.disk3s1
sudo mount-bitlocker /dev/disk3s1 PASSWORD

# unmount
sudo umount-bitlocker /dev/disk3s1
```

Comment: This is the only right answer that is up-to-date. Not even the dislocker github is updated.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this still works (October 2nd, 2018). However, both the dislocker unlock command and the gist mount the volume as read-only. When full access (read/write) is required, remove the "-r" option from the dislocker command and/or edit the gist mount-bitlocker by removing "-r".

Answer (score -1):

Alternative solution

Use Windows in virtual machine. Pass through the USB device to the VM and share back to host macOS.

I haven't tried it but it should work theoretically.